# jQuery - set button title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the title of a button using `jQuery`

```
<button id="pub2" class="pub2" title="ok">Bibtex</button> 
<script>Tippy('.pub2', {interactive : true})</script>
```

Also, I have a small paragraph to test

```
<p id="testP">
   text
</p>
```

To change the properties, I'm doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#testP").text("test worked");
   $("#pub2").attr("title", "new title not working");
});
```

Updating the text of the paragraph works just fine, but the title of the button won't change, why?

Comment: Your example works perfectly

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: what's the use of `<script>Tippy('.pub2', {interactive : true})</script>`? can you please tell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code working fine:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testP").text("test worked");
    $("#pub2").attr("title", "new title not working");// you can use prop() also
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="pub2" class="pub2" title="ok"> Bibtex </button> 

<p id="testP">
 text
</p>
```

Note:-

You have this code under button

```
<script>Tippy('.pub2', {interactive : true})</script>
```

Try to remove it from there and add into you script code like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#testP").text("test worked");
  Tippy('.pub2', {interactive : true})
  $("#pub2").attr("title", "new title not working");// you can use prop() also
});
```

Comment: I checked for js errors in the browser console but there is no error. Plus i put javascripts alerts after both jquery statements but they are both running.

Comment: do you have this much html or more html is there? May be id `pub2` is repeated somewhere?Please check

Comment: I just go this working, by putting the tippy declaration under the jquery statement, and not under the button declaration as i did.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:
HTML:

```
<button id="pub2" class="pub2" title="ok"> Bibtex </button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#pub2").prop("title", "new title not working");
```